# Is it possible to save video call via WebRTC or web socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am on my way of learning javascript by developing some cool stuff like video conferencing app. I don't have much understanding of this webRTC technology so I am wondering if it is also possible to save video call to the server which has been taken place on webRTC based video conferencing app ?

Comment: Oh my my my. With respect, this is a bit like learning to climb mountains by going to Everest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can record each stream to blobs and push them to your server with websocket. You can then convert the blobs to a webm file.

Demo: video https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We prefer answers that don't completely rely on a link. Maybe [edit] your answer to add a few details from the webrtc demo code?